# XCode: Unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, selector

I am getting the following error:

"-[Order items]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b5f240"

I do have a class called Order, which looks like this:

Order.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class OrderItem;

@interface Order : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * orderID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * date;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * orderCode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* items;

@end
```

Order.m

```
#import "Order.h"
#import "OrderItem.h"


@implementation Order
@dynamic orderID;
@dynamic date;
@dynamic orderCode;
@dynamic items;

...
```

It doesn't extend any sort of class which has an "items" method, if I'm reading that correctly?

Is there any other reason I would be getting such an error. To add to the madness, this project is copied directly from a previous project, with some minor edits. I've done text comparisons on every single class in both projects and there are no differences other than the cosmetic changes I've made.

Comment: Did you generate this class from a .xcdatamodeld file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@dynamic items` tells the compiler that you will be providing the methods for `items`.

Since this was working in a previous project, it must have had the following method somewhere in the .m file:

```
- (NSSet *)items {
    // Appropriate code
}
```

If you do not want to provide your own custom getter like this, then change `@dynamic items` to `@synthesize items` and the compiler will generate one for you.

For more details, see the **Declared Properties** section of **The Objective-C Programming Language** provided by Apple here:  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html

**EDIT**
While everything above still applies to a normal object (and may still apply here), I just noticed that this is a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

In your old data model there was probably a relationship called `items` and therefore the appropriate methods were provided by NSManagedObject and `@dynamic` was appropriate to prevent compiler warnings.

If in your new data model there is no relationship named `items`, then the methods will not be generated and it will cause the problem that you are getting here.