# "Unrecognized selector sent to instance", even though XCode says the instance is the right type

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4.6

In a mac desktop app, I'm getting an "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" error.

Here's the line that causes the error:

```
    My_WebView *mvw = [mWebView LoadHtml];
```

And here's the relevant class definition:

My_WebView.h

```
    #import <WebKit/WebKit.h>  

    @interface My_WebView : WebView
    {
    }

    - (My_WebView *) LoadHtml; // initialize the WebView with a page

    @end
```

My_WebView.mm

```
    #import  "My_WebView.h"

    @implementation My_WebView

    - (My_WebView *) LoadHtml
    {
        NSLog(@"Loading HTML...");
        // do stuff...
        return self;
    }

    @end
```

When I run my code in the XCode debugger and break at the offending line, I'm told that `mWebView` is of the expected type (`My_WebView`). This rules out the problems identified in the many [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455161/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474138/xcode-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance) [I've seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861603/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance).

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How are you instantiating mWebView? Are you checking that mWebView is not nil?

Comment: Did you actually log the instance, the type you saw may be a lie...

Comment: I'll try that... how do I log the instance? (I'm a major Cocoa newbie.)

Comment: Re: logging, ok, got it: `NSLog(@"mWebView: %@", mWebView);`  I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: Or from the debugger, `po mWebView` (assuming that you're in a stack frame where `mWebView` is accessible). You can log the result of any expression using either `po` (for objects) or `p` (for non-objects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was confused. The instance *wasn't* the right type!

The XCode debugger said that `mWebView` was a pointer to a `My_WebView`.

```
    mWebView    My_WebView *    0x000000010e0884c0
```

This led me to think, wrongly, that `My_WebView` was also the runtime type of `mWebView`. It wasn't, as `NSLog(@"mWebView: %@", mWebView);` and `po mWebView` revealed.

```
     mWebView: <WebView: 0x1180ca4c0>
```

`mWebView` was actually just a plain old Cocoa `WebView`. That's why it wasn't responding to a `LoadHTML` message. Problem solved.